# Compute Engine SSH unexpected end-of-file during FileZilla SFTP authentication

Tags: ssh, authentication, google-compute-engine

I cannot get Filezilla to connect to my SSH instances at Google Cloud Compute Engine.

I [followed the instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#generatesshkeypair) for previous instances without issue, but in this case, I deleted two Ubuntu 16.04 server instances from my project so that I could recreate them with Cloud Storage Read/Write enabled.

Even after manually creating the keys and placing them in the Metadata page for my project, I cannot connect FileZilla to my instances. I get the error: "Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server."

I have tried both root@instance and root as my -C [USERNAME] but neither works.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the issue specific to Filezilla? Are you able to connect via SSH to inspect the disk? If you are able to SSH you can confirm what keys are in the server for a particular user by listing  ¨cat $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys¨
I would also try to configure another SFTP client like [WinSCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSCP). Is the connection established and the error obtained while transferring files?

Comment: If you were able to solve this, you can post the answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue. If not, you can provide further information as Carlos suggested to further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice step by step configuration guide to setup Filezilla and use it on GCE [here](http://blog.sandeepdinesh.com/2015/04/how-to-setup-filezilla-for-google.html). 
An easy and automated way to configure the keys is by using “[gcloud compute ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh)”. If the keys do not exists, the tool will generate them and configure them in the project’s metadata.  The keys are placed in the local “[.ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh)” directory